# How to implement offcanvas on selected breakpoint on react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I did the navbar `offcanvas` across all breakpoints using the attribute `expand={false}` **like the image below**.
[image]

However i want the navbar items to be like the normal navigation on `(min-width: 992px) OR expand="lg"` **like the image below**. Im using [reactrouter v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6) and [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/).
[image]

Below is my code and also here is the working sandbox code [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-bootstrap-offcanvas-menu-1tx0n).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Container, Navbar, Nav, Offcanvas } from "react-bootstrap";
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const NavbarContent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar
        expanded={isOpen}
        expand={false}
        bg="light"
        fixed="top"
        className="bg-white text-the-primary bg-gradient shadow py-3"
      >
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">
            <span className="d-block fs-1">Offcanvas</span>{" "}
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle
            aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar"
            onClick={() => setOpen(isOpen ? false : "expanded")}
          />
          <Navbar.Offcanvas
            id="offcanvasNavbar"
            aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel"
            placement="end"
          >
            <Offcanvas.Header
              closeButton
              className="justify-content-end"
              onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
            ></Offcanvas.Header>
            <Offcanvas.Body>
              <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-0">
                <NavLink to="/" onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
                  Home
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/About" onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
                  About
                </NavLink>
              </Nav>
            </Offcanvas.Body>
          </Navbar.Offcanvas>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

export default NavbarContent;
```

I'm not sure if I missed something on `useState` and `expand` attribute of the navbar.

Comment: Where are you trying to set the media query?

Comment: any workaround or possible solutions.

Comment: Hello @clarkf have you found a solution yet? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have no solution yet, what I did is I have two navigation with the same source of text components, one is the normal Navbar visible only on (min-width: 992px) and the other is the Offcanvas visible only less than 992px.

Comment: Hey @clarkf bootstrap released 5.2.0 which now comes with responsive offcanvas: https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2022/05/13/bootstrap-5-2-0-beta/#responsive-offcanvas
Lets hope `react-bootstrap` will implement this asap.

Answer (score 0):

Set the expand break point to large using the command

```
<Navbar
  expanded={isOpen}
  expand='lg'
  ...
/>
```

Works for me

Comment: But it still doesn't cover the fact that the menu/nav on 'lg' is nowhere to be seen. Since the nav is now inside the Offcanvas it does not cover for `<Navbar.Collapse>` which is basically what we need. So that on `expand='lg'` the nav is visible and on lower res it will be collapsed.

Comment: Works fine on my end. I think the problem should be from the versions of packages used   ```"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",``` these are the packages I used